# How to load dictionary from an url of a plist file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a plist file in my bundle and I convert it to a dictionary using:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myFile", ofType: "plist")
let dicFromFile = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path!)
myDictionary = dicFromFile as! [String : String]
```

But I also want the app to check for update of this file, so I put it on a sharing site, so it has some url, like so:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ri13i2wggaz6/myFile.plist
```

so, how do I make NSDictionary to read from this file's url?

Comment: plist dictionary should be `[String : Any]` but not `[String : String]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load data from a remote URL use an asynchronous way and the class `PropertyListSerialization` to deserialize the property list.

```
let url = URL(string:"https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ri13i2wggaz6/myFile.plist"
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, response, error) in
   if let error = error { print(error); return }
   do {
      let dictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data!, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
      // do something with the dictionary
   } catch {
      print(error)
   }    
}.resume()
```

If the property list file contains only `String` values – as assumed in the question – cast to `[String:String]`

Comment: Everything looks right, but it just doesn't work, it neither gives me an error nor giving me right data

Answer (score -1):

OBJ-C

```
NSMutableDictionary *autos = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                                 [NSURL urlWithString:@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ri13i2wggaz6/myFile.plist"]];
```

swift

```
let path = NSURL.init(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ri13i2wggaz6/myFile.plist")
        let dicFromFile = let dicFromFile = NSDictionary.init(contentsOf: path as! URL)
        myDictionary = dicFromFile as! [String : String]
```

Comment: **Never** use synchronous methods to load data from a remote URL

Comment: it seems to be working, but it gives me 'nil' value. Maybe it does have to do with dropbox, but if you just open the link, it does open the file